# Can inner block synchronized improve performance of a method already synchronized?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, synchronized

Given a theoretical system in which files are downloaded from the Web if not found in the local system and assuming:

1. Download mechanism and retrieval/placement from/in cache (local
   files system) are already taken care of.
2. Single-threaded and single request per URL.

I wrote a method that uses getFileFromLocalFS() and getFileFromWeb() to implement a simplified logic of caching:

```
public InputStream getFile(String url) { // #1
    InputStream retStream = getFileFromLocalFS(url);
    if (retStream != null) {
        return retStream;           
    }
    else {
        retStream = getFileFromLocalFS(url);
        if (retStream == null) {
            return getFileFromWeb(url);
        }
    }
    return retStream;
}
```

This schematic solution then needed to be improved to accommodate **concurrent** requests to download from same URL...and limit actual "from Web" to a **single** download (i.e. all other requests will get it from the local file system). So, I synchronized the entire method:

```
public synchronized InputStream getFile(String url) { // #2
    InputStream retStream = getFileFromLocalFS(url);
    if (retStream != null) {
        return retStream;           
    }
    else {
        retStream = getFileFromLocalFS(url);
        if (retStream == null) {
            return getFileFromWeb(url);
        }
    }
    return retStream;
}
```

This essentially meets the request but has a performance issue as it prevents the entire method from being run by another thread until it finishes. That is, even if the file can be fetched form the local FS, `getFileFromLocalFS(url)` cannot be accessed while the method is run by another thread.

A performance improvement suggested by my interviewer was to synchronize the `getFileFromLocalFS(url)` block:

```
public synchronized InputStream getFile(String url) { // #3
    InputStream retStream = getFileFromLocalFS(url);
    if (retStream != null) {
        return retStream;           
    }
    else {
        synchronized (this) { 
            retStream = getFileFromLocalFS(url);
            if (retStream == null) {
                return getFileFromWeb(url);
            }
        }
    }
    return retStream;
}
```

I said "fine, but for that optimization to work, the method synchronization needs to be removed", i.e.:

```
public InputStream getFile(String url) { // #4
    InputStream retStream = getFileFromLocalFS(url);
    if (retStream != null) {
        return retStream;           
    }
    else {
        synchronized (this) { 
            retStream = getFileFromLocalFS(url);
            if (retStream == null) {
                return getFileFromWeb(url);
            }
        }
    }
    return retStream;
}
```

The interviewer disagreed and insisted on leaving **both** `synchronized` in place.

Which one would perform better in a concurrency environment? #3 or #4? Why?

Comment: The nested synchronized is entirely unnecessary, as you're just locking on the same monitor you're already locked on. In other words, #3 won't improve anything. Whether it would be correct to remove `synchronized` from the method declaration depends on what `getFileFromLocalFS` does, and whether or not it is thread-safe on its own. In other words, given the information, it is not possible to say if #4 is correct.

Comment: #4 would be the best. You don't need to synchronize the whole method

Comment: Are there other callers of `getFileFromLocalFS` or is this method only invoked from `getFile`?

Comment: @Holger for the purpose of this interview question (I didn't make it up, I was actually asked this in a real job interview), one can assume that  `getFileFromLocalFS` is only invoked from `getFile`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There seems to be [Cargo Cult Programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming) going on. The third variant resembles [Double-Checked Locking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-checked_locking) but doesn’t get the point. But even more striking, the *first variant* also resembles Double-Checked Locking, by calling `getFileFromLocalFS(url)` twice without a reason. And that’s the starting point…

Your suspicion against the interviewer’s “improvement” is right. Nested synchronization serves no purpose and in the best case, the JVM’s optimizer will be able to eliminate it.

However, neither solution is recommended. There’s a much deeper problem here. First, we should focus on *correctness*, before discussing performance.

Apparently, `getFileFromLocalFS(url)` is supposed to find a local copy if it exists, but not to create it. This would be pointless if no-one ever creates such copies and the whole question about overlapping caching attempts would be moot, if this method doesn’t perform the caching attempt. So the only other method involved, `getFileFromWeb(url)` must be the one which creates the local copy.

This implies that there is a *hidden protocol* between these two methods. `getFileFromLocalFS(url)` somehow knows, how to get the cached file created by `getFileFromWeb(url)`.

This raises questions, like, what happens if one thread is in the middle of `getFileFromWeb(url)` creating a cached version and another thread calls `getFileFromLocalFS(url)` for the same url? Does it return an input stream to the still incomplete local file? There are two possibilities:

1. This issue has been solved somehow. This would imply that there is already some thread safe construct behind the scenes to prevent such a race condition, hence, it should be used by `getFileFromWeb(url)` to also solve the issue of multiple caching attempts in the first place.
2. Or this issue wasn’t solved and the starting point was a *broken* method, so the first task should be to fix this, instead of trying to improve the performance. If we really try to fix this outside the two methods, i.e. in `getFile`, only the second variant would be correct, calling both methods inside `synchronized`.

In either case, the `getFile` method is the wrong place to address the issue. The concurrency issues should be addressed by the *hidden protocol* that already exists between the two methods.

For example:

- If these two methods use a map from url to local file, they should use a [concurrent map](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentMap.html) und its atomic update operations to solve the concurrency issues.
- If these two methods use a mapping scheme to convert the url to a local path where the copy is supposed to be, and the `getFileFromLocalFS(url)` method merely checks for the presence of the file, the `getFileFromWeb(url)` method should create the file with the [`CREATE_NEW`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/StandardOpenOption.html#CREATE_NEW) option to atomically check the presence and create if not present, together with file locking to prevent other threads from reading while the caching is still in progress.

Comment: I find it ironic the link to Caro Cult Programming in a SO answer, a place where many Cargo Cult Programmers go to to solve their problems :-)

Answer (score 1):

Both of them are basically (somewhat obscured) versions of the [double-checked locking pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-checked_locking). But seeing as the call to `getFileFromLocalFS(url)` could itself be costly (it's an I/O call, which are always more costly than in-memory operations), this form of the pattern isn't really ideal. Ideally an implementation of Double-checked Locking should do so as "tight" as possible - meaning the two locks should be as near each other as possible.

The extra synchronization in #3 (the interviewer's suggestion) does impose additional overhead and, more importantly, potentially blocks when it doesn't need to. "Performance" is a broad term that can mean different things to different people and in different contexts; but that extra synchronization could (likely?) impact *observed throughput* significantly depending on circumstances.

Comment: I'll leave this answer for reference, but note that the accepted answer by @Holger says the same thing with more elaboration and is a better answer. It was posted while mine was sitting in draft status and SO didn't show it to me until after I clicked Submit.